# Insert characters in batch (using the notepad)

Tags: batch-file, symbols, notepad

I'm making a batch program and I know that if you put (in Notepad) É, È, Í, º, », ¼, you can make a pipe box (like ‖). So actually I can make a box with those symbols.

MY QUESTION: How can I put this symbol (╩) in the batch? Not INSIDE the batch, using the NOTEPAD.

Thank you and excuse my grammar mistakes!

-- I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION: Windows+R --> write "charmap" set it to the Terminal Font and click the symbol you want until it apears at the "Characters to copy" box. You copy the symbol with the Copy button et Voilà!!

Comment: so you want to print these symbols on the screen?

Comment: There is some information here about line drawing characters, and notepad.  Read the two posts and further. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36574#p36574

Comment: Thanks for the hint with **Terminal** font. This was driving me nuts; not to be able to copy/paste those symbols!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question you want to print extended ascii characters that can be used to build rectangulars/boxes. You can use [Dave Benham's hexprint function](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3857)  .Bellow you can find a script that generates these characters and stores them in variables that you can use.I think they are [Char Code page](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) independent , but I've put  `chcp 437` just in case.If you try to print them to a text file [they will not look the same](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36574#p36574) , but as long as you use them in the console you can use them:

```
@echo off
chcp 437
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::Define a Linefeed variable
set LF=^


::above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove.


::Create a string variable with encoded TABs

call :hexprint "0xB0" var1 
call :hexprint "0xB1" var2
call :hexprint "0xB2" var3
call :hexprint "0xB3" var4
call :hexprint "0xB4" var5
call :hexprint "0xB5" var6
call :hexprint "0xB6" var7
call :hexprint "0xB7" var8
call :hexprint "0xB8" var9
call :hexprint "0xB9" var10
call :hexprint "0xBA" var11
call :hexprint "0xBB" var12
call :hexprint "0xBC" var13
call :hexprint "0xBD" var14
call :hexprint "0xBE" var15
call :hexprint "0xBF" var16
call :hexprint "0xC0" var17
call :hexprint "0xC1" var18
call :hexprint "0xC2" var19
call :hexprint "0xC3" var20
call :hexprint "0xC4" var21
call :hexprint "0xC5" var22
call :hexprint "0xC6" var23
call :hexprint "0xC7" var24
call :hexprint "0xC8" var25
call :hexprint "0xC9" var26
call :hexprint "0xCA" var27
call :hexprint "0xCB" var28
call :hexprint "0xCC" var29
call :hexprint "0xCD" var30
call :hexprint "0xCE" var31
call :hexprint "0xCF" var32
call :hexprint "0xD0" var33
call :hexprint "0xD1" var34
call :hexprint "0xD2" var35
call :hexprint "0xD3" var36
call :hexprint "0xD4" var37
call :hexprint "0xD5" var38
call :hexprint "0xD6" var39
call :hexprint "0xD7" var40
call :hexprint "0xD8" var41
call :hexprint "0xD9" var42
call :hexprint "0xDA" var43
call :hexprint "0xDB" var44

for /l %%@ in (1;1;44) do (
    echo var%%@ : !var%%@!
)
exit /b

:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar]
  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A
exit /b
```